# How to convert a date format YYYY-MM-DD into integer YYYYMMDD in Presto/Hive?

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, presto

How to `CONVERT` a date in format `YYYY-MM-DD` into integer `YYYYMMDD` in Presto/Hive?

I am trying to convert the below list into `YYYYMMDD` integers

```
WITH  all_dates  as (SELECT
    CAST(date_column AS DATE) date_column
FROM
    (VALUES
        (SEQUENCE(FROM_ISO8601_DATE('2017-07-01'),
                  FROM_ISO8601_DATE('2017-11-15'),
                  INTERVAL '1' DAY)
        )
    ) AS t1(date_array)
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(date_array) AS t2(date_column)
    )
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
   SELECT
   CAST(
      CAST(year(date_column) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      right('0' + CAST(month(date_column) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      right('0' + CAST(day(date_column) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS DATETIME)
   FROM all_dates
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to transform your date *YYYY-MM-DD* into an integer *YYYYMMDD* why don't you try to first remove all the occurrences of `"-"` from the string representation of your date before casting the result to int by using something like this?

```
cast(regexp_replace(str_column,'-','') as int)
```

Answer (score 12):

Also you can use `date_format` function:

```
hive> select cast(date_format('2017-07-01','yyyyMMdd') as int);
OK
20170701
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply `REPLACE` the '-' with Empty string and `CAST` it into `INT`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(Date_Column,'-','') AS INT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to use `YYYYMMDD` ?
Hive follows Java convention for Date Formatting and as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
you can see that YYYY represents week year which means you may get into trouble for end of the year dates. 2019 may appear as 2020.

Use `yyyyMMdd` instead.

@leftjoin has probably the correct respone.

```
beeline> select cast(date_format('2019-07-01','yyyyMMdd') as int);
OK
20190701
```